# Best ways to save constants in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to save a number of constants, and these should always works as one group, ex:
when I call the first group, should get all the data from the first group and  I have to take this data and save it in an excel file.

```
Group One:
speed = 45,
color = 12,
height = 23

Group Two:
speed = 450,
color = 128,
height = 13

Group Three:
speed = 15,
color = 542,
height = 23
```

Is the best way to save these values in enum or List of type Tuple?

Enum:

```
public enum Group_One
{            
    speed = 45,
    color = 12,
    height = 23
}
```

List

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> Group_One = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create("speed", "45"),
    Tuple.Create("color", "12"),
    Tuple.Create("height", "23")
};
```

Comment: Why not `struct` with fields `int speed, color, height`, so that each group is a seperate instance of this struct?

Comment: In newer versions of C# this would be an excellent candidate for a record: `record Widget(int Speed, int Color, int Height)`.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov srry I have not exactly explained, the there are more constants than these, Group Four: have Speed, Color, Current, Id... etc

Answer (score 5):

Create a class:

```
public class ConstantsCollection
{
   public int Speed {get;}
   public int Color {get;}
   public int Height {get;}

   public ConstantsCollection(int speed, int color, int height)
   {
     Speed = speed;
     Color = color;
     Height = height;
   }
}
```

Then create your three groups:

```
public static readonly ConstantsCollection group1 = new ConstantsCollection(45, 12, 23);
// same for the other groups
```

You can think of a better name for your class. From your question, I don't know what your constants represent. It has a speed, so maybe a vehicle? In that case, call your class `Vehicle`.

Comment: may be it is better to use a record ?

Comment: If there are only three ints you could consider using a (readonly) struct instead of a class.

Comment: probably an additional property `GroupID` would be good for filtering

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use records and use readonly values:

```
public struct record Group(int Speed, int Color, int Height);

public static class GroupManager
{
    public static readonly Group GROUP_ONE = new(45, 12, 13);
    public static readonly Group GROUP_TWO = new(450, 128, 13);
    public static readonly Group GROUP_THREE = new(15, 542, 23);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of keeping them together and using them as groups is using dictionaries as follows:

```
        var groups = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

        var firstGroupValues = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "spped", 45 },
            { "color", 12 },
            { "height", 13 }
        };
        groups.Add("Group One", firstGroupValues);
```

Then, you can use them as follows: `var result = groups["Group One"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a class, something like this:

```
public class MyClass //call it something useful
{
    public int Speed {get;}
    public int Color {get;}
    public int Height {get;}
    //Any other associated variables

    
    public MyClass (int group) // You can use this constructor for the default groups
    {
       if (group == 1) {
           //set defaults for group one
       }
       else if (group == 2){
           //set defaults for group two
       }
       else if (group ==3) {
           //set defaults for group three
       }
       else {
           //deal with the invalid group number entry
       }
    }
    
    public MyClass (int speed, int color, int height) //constructor for different groups
    {
        Speed = speed;
        Height = height;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

To create your default 3 groups you'd then just do something along the lines of:

```
List<MyClass> groups = new List<MyClass>();
for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++) 
{
    groups.Add(new MyClass(i)); 
}
```

There are alternatives, depending on your use case (which you've been relatively vague about), but this way provides the most flexibility (and, I guess, future-proofing).